# POST request and headers in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, header, request, phantomjs

I'm trying to add functionality to a headless webbrowser. I know there are easier ways but I stumbled across `seleniumrequests` an it sparked my interest. I was wondering if there would be a way to add request headers as well as being able to `POST` data as a payload. I've done some searching around and haven't had much luck. The following prints the html of the first website and screenshots for verification and then my program just hangs on the `POST` request. Doesn't terminate or raise an exception or anything. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from seleniumrequests import PhantomJS
from selenium import webdriver

#Setting user-agent  
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/37.0.2062.120 Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36'

browser = PhantomJS()

browser.get('http://www.google.com')
print browser.page_source
browser.save_screenshot('preSearch.png')

searchReq='https://www.google.com/complete/search?'
data={"q":"this is my search term"}
resp = browser.request('POST', str(searchReq), data=data)

print resp
browser.save_screenshot('postSearch.png')
```

Comment: Copied your script verbatim and it's not hanging on my system.  I get the print of the page source, the preSearch.png, the <Response [405]> resp print, and the postSearch.png file.  I'm running python 2.7.10, node v5.9.1, phantomjs 2.1.3, selenium 2.53.1, and selenium-requests 1.2.7.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @clockwatcher It's been a few months since you posted but I noticed you say you are using phantomjs 2.1.3, the latest is 2.1.1. I have a similar issue to the one posted above. From what I have read it only works with phantomjs < 2.0.